# Create instance of a type in another domain without assembly name

Tags: c#, reflection

How can I create an instance of a type in another domain without needing to assembly stored on hard drive. My assemblies need some pre-process to load on memory and I cannot use their name to create instance.

For example I cannot use this code, because it loads assembly from hard drive and my assemblies are not in normal mode:

```
MyType t = _domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap("AssemblyName", myType.FullName) as MyType;
```

Comment: How you create the assembly in memory ? I believe there are many ways. Can you add the code ?

Comment: No, I decrypt my encrypted assembly and load it on memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this method... (using System.Linq)

```
    public static Object GetInstanceFrom(AppDomain domain, string typeFullName)
    {
        Object objectInstance = null;

        var myAssembly = domain.GetAssemblies().Where(w => w.GetTypes().Select(s => s.FullName.ToUpperInvariant()).Contains(typeFullName.ToUpperInvariant())).FirstOrDefault();

        if (myAssembly != null)
        {
            var myTypeFromAssembly = myAssembly.GetTypes().Where(w => w.FullName.ToUpperInvariant() == typeFullName.ToUpperInvariant()).FirstOrDefault();
            if (myTypeFromAssembly != null)
            {
                objectInstance = System.Activator.CreateInstance(myTypeFromAssembly);
            }
        }

        return objectInstance;
    }
```

Comment: dont Forget to load assembly into the 2nd appdomain 1rst : ((System.AppDomain)anotherDomain).Load()

Comment: If we use the Type gotten from assembly of another domain to create an instance, we create an instance in that domain?